# Отображение границ ячеек в Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Я создаю таблицу по Xml файлу на данный момент она выглядит так:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как реализовать отображение границ у таблицы, чтобы было видно границы ячеек. Заранее благодарен.

```
import xml.etree.cElementTree as et
import pandas as pd
def getvalueofnode(node):
    """ return node text or None """
    return node.text if node is not None else None


def main():
    """ main """
    parsed_xml = et.parse("book.xml")
    dfcols = ['author', 'name', 'publich', 'year','page']
    df_xml = pd.DataFrame(columns=dfcols)

    for node in parsed_xml.getroot():
        author=node.find('author')
        name = node.find('name')
        publich = node.find('publich')
        year = node.find('year')
        page = node.find('page')

        df_xml = df_xml.append(
            pd.Series([getvalueofnode(author), getvalueofnode(name), getvalueofnode(publich),
                       getvalueofnode(year),getvalueofnode(page)], index=dfcols),
            ignore_index=True)

    print df_xml

main()
```

Comment: что вы хотите получить на выходе? HTML или ASCII таблицу?

Comment: @MaxU вообще не принципиально, что проще реализуется

Answer (score 1):

Пример сохранения Pandas DataFrame в HTML:

```
In [229]: d = pd.DataFrame({'author':['aaa','bbbbbbb','ccccccccc'], 'name':['book 1','book 11','book 111']})

In [230]: d
Out[230]:
      author      name
0        aaa    book 1
1    bbbbbbb   book 11
2  ccccccccc  book 111

In [231]: d.to_html(r'c:\temp\out.html', index=False)
```

Результат:

```html
<table border="1" class="dataframe">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>author</th>
      <th>name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>aaa</td>
      <td>book 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>bbbbbbb</td>
      <td>book 11</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>ccccccccc</td>
      <td>book 111</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```